# MySQL DDL script with foreign key relationships

Tags: mysql

I reverse engineered a MySQL database into MySQL Workbench--the foreign key relationships are not there. I then went to phpMyAdmin and did an SQL dump. The foreign key relationships are not defined in the script. Is it possible to have the foreign key relationships included in the SQL dump?

**Background Information:**
When setting up the options for the DDL script, under the 'Structure' section of the export I selected two options: 
- Add AUTO_INCREMENT value, and
- Enclose table and field names with backquotes.

The engine is InnoDB. I'm using MAMP community edition.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that db doesn't have FK rel-s at all, can this be the case?

Comment: Thanks for your response Petr Abdulin. The database has a number of fk relationships.